# Arduino AES128 - CMAC

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm looking for ***AES128*** library with ***CMAC*** for Arduino. Help me to find one

Comment: Did you ask Professor [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=aes128+arduino+library+cmac&oq=aes128+arduino+library+cmac&aqs=chrome..69i57.9580j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)?

Comment: Yes, i search in google but i don't find any library aes128 cmac with example to use it, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I happen to know some libraries which use this. AES128-CMAC is for example used in the LoRaWAN MAC / driver implementation (LoRa is a low-power-wide-range radio technology). For example, the library Arduino-LMIC (**L**oRa **M**AC **i**n **C**) uses this AES-CMAC implementation (has actually 2 built-in, Ideetron is the other one):

- https://github.com/matthijskooijman/arduino-lmic/tree/master/src/aes

Other stacks use the mbedtls library with only the AES and CMAC layer activated. The library, written by ARM, is entirely in C and thus easily configrable (`config.h`) and compilable for the Arduino platform:

- https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls
- https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls/blob/development/library/cmac.c

Semetech's LoRa stack even has AES and CMAC abstracted in 4 four files:

- https://github.com/arduino-org/arduino-library-lora-node-shield/tree/master/src/system/crypto

Another good point would be to search PlatformIO's library index for "AES CMAC". Then this library comes up:

- https://platformio.org/lib/search?query=AES%20CMAC
- https://github.com/DavyLandman/AESLib

This also offers a CMAC implementation specifically designed for the Atmel AVR MCUs (Arduino Uno and likes) and partially written in Assembler. This should be best suited for you.

- https://github.com/DavyLandman/AESLib/blob/master/bcal-cmac.c

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am already working on **LoraWan** device and a network server .